# Is there a way to include a watermark image in dygraphs?

Tags: javascript, plot, charts, watermark, dygraphs

Is it possible to add a background watermark image to a dygraphs chart?

I could not find this information anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS to set a `background-image` on the chart's container `<div>`. The chart canvas is mostly transparent, so this should work find for a watermark.